# Oracle SQL get last year of dates excluding weekends

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd expect this to work to get me a list of calendar dates over the past 12 months excluding weekends; but it just gives me the entire list of dates - which I suppose is fine - but want to know why the below is incorrect.

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) - 1 + rownum AS CalendarDate
FROM all_objects
WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) - 1 + rownum <= sysdate
AND to_char(sysdate,'DY') NOT IN ('SAT','SUN')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're doing this:

```
AND to_char(sysdate,'DY') NOT IN ('SAT','SUN')
```

And *today* isn't Saturday or Sunday. You need to look at the calculated CalendarDate value; but you can't do that in the same level of subquery. You could try to recalculate it:

```
AND to_char(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) - 1 + rownum,'DY') NOT IN ('SAT','SUN')
```

but this will return no rows - at least when run at the moment. As it happens, March 1st 2020 was a Sunday, so that is excluded; and because of when and how `rownum` is generated, that result is excluded, and the next one sees the same value, which is excluded, and so on.

You can use an inline view to avoid both issues:

```
SELECT CalendarDate
FROM (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) - 1 + rownum AS CalendarDate
  FROM all_objects
  WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) - 1 + rownum <= sysdate
)
WHERE to_char(CalendarDate,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT','SUN')

CALENDARDATE
02-MAR-20
03-MAR-20
04-MAR-20
05-MAR-20
06-MAR-20
09-MAR-20
10-MAR-20
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=548eaa1d38af0e1c2e08a822df3d9457)

I've chucked in a language modifier to stop it behaving differently for users with sessions not set to English.

Querying against `all_objects` isn't ideal though, it would be better to use a hierarcical query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) - 1 + level AS CalendarDate
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) + 1
)
WHERE to_char(CalendarDate,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT','SUN')
ORDER BY CalendarDate
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=07cea67e30ad74a010b8acd7ac149b16)

or a recursive CTE, if you're 11gR2+:

```
WITH rcte (CalendarDate) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12)
  FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rcte.CalendarDate + interval '1' day
  FROM rcte
  WHERE rcte.CalendarDate < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
)
SELECT CalendarDate
FROM rcte
WHERE to_char(CalendarDate,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT','SUN')
ORDER BY CalendarDate
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa1f6c11ef5f55ed9a83e2e4c2485e29) (as 18c to avoid a couple of issues with the patch level in the 11g version it uses).

Answer (score 1):

You checking whether today is sunday or monday with  **to_char(sysdate,'DY')**. you need to check CalendarDate which is not available in your window. You can use cte to calculate the calendar then you can remove weekends with your condition as below.

> ```
> with cte (CalendarDate) as
> (
> SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) - 1 + rownum AS CalendarDate
> FROM all_objects
> WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-12) - 1 + rownum <= sysdate
> )
> select * from cte where 
>  to_char(CalendarDate,'DY') not in ('SAT','SUN');
> ```

> ```
> | CALENDARDATE |
> | :----------- |
> | 02-MAR-20    |
> | 03-MAR-20    |
> | 04-MAR-20    |
> | 05-MAR-20    |
> | 06-MAR-20    |
> | 09-MAR-20    |
> | 10-MAR-20    |
> | 11-MAR-20    |
> | 12-MAR-20    |
> | 13-MAR-20    |
> | 16-MAR-20    |
> | 17-MAR-20    |
> | 18-MAR-20    |
> | 19-MAR-20    |
> | 20-MAR-20    |
> | 23-MAR-20    |
> | 24-MAR-20    |
> | 25-MAR-20    |
> | 26-MAR-20    |
> | 27-MAR-20    |
> | 30-MAR-20    |
> | 31-MAR-20    |
> | 01-APR-20    |
> | 02-APR-20    |
> | 03-APR-20    |
> | 06-APR-20    |
> | 07-APR-20    |
> | 08-APR-20    |
> | 09-APR-20    |
> | 10-APR-20    |
> | 13-APR-20    |
> | 14-APR-20    |
> | 15-APR-20    |
> | 16-APR-20    |
> | 17-APR-20    |
> | 20-APR-20    |
> | 21-APR-20    |
> | 22-APR-20    |
> | 23-APR-20    |
> | 24-APR-20    |
> | 27-APR-20    |
> | 28-APR-20    |
> | 29-APR-20    |
> | 30-APR-20    |
> | 01-MAY-20    |
> | 04-MAY-20    |
> | 05-MAY-20    |
> | 06-MAY-20    |
> | 07-MAY-20    |
> | 08-MAY-20    |
> | 11-MAY-20    |
> | 12-MAY-20    |
> | 13-MAY-20    |
> | 14-MAY-20    |
> | 15-MAY-20    |
> | 18-MAY-20    |
> | 19-MAY-20    |
> | 20-MAY-20    |
> | 21-MAY-20    |
> | 22-MAY-20    |
> | 25-MAY-20    |
> | 26-MAY-20    |
> | 27-MAY-20    |
> | 28-MAY-20    |
> | 29-MAY-20    |
> | 01-JUN-20    |
> | 02-JUN-20    |
> | 03-JUN-20    |
> | 04-JUN-20    |
> | 05-JUN-20    |
> | 08-JUN-20    |
> | 09-JUN-20    |
> | 10-JUN-20    |
> | 11-JUN-20    |
> | 12-JUN-20    |
> | 15-JUN-20    |
> | 16-JUN-20    |
> | 17-JUN-20    |
> | 18-JUN-20    |
> | 19-JUN-20    |
> | 22-JUN-20    |
> | 23-JUN-20    |
> | 24-JUN-20    |
> | 25-JUN-20    |
> | 26-JUN-20    |
> | 29-JUN-20    |
> | 30-JUN-20    |
> | 01-JUL-20    |
> | 02-JUL-20    |
> | 03-JUL-20    |
> | 06-JUL-20    |
> | 07-JUL-20    |
> | 08-JUL-20    |
> | 09-JUL-20    |
> | 10-JUL-20    |
> | 13-JUL-20    |
> | 14-JUL-20    |
> | 15-JUL-20    |
> | 16-JUL-20    |
> | 17-JUL-20    |
> | 20-JUL-20    |
> | 21-JUL-20    |
> | 22-JUL-20    |
> | 23-JUL-20    |
> | 24-JUL-20    |
> | 27-JUL-20    |
> | 28-JUL-20    |
> | 29-JUL-20    |
> | 30-JUL-20    |
> | 31-JUL-20    |
> | 03-AUG-20    |
> | 04-AUG-20    |
> | 05-AUG-20    |
> | 06-AUG-20    |
> | 07-AUG-20    |
> | 10-AUG-20    |
> | 11-AUG-20    |
> | 12-AUG-20    |
> | 13-AUG-20    |
> | 14-AUG-20    |
> | 17-AUG-20    |
> | 18-AUG-20    |
> | 19-AUG-20    |
> | 20-AUG-20    |
> | 21-AUG-20    |
> | 24-AUG-20    |
> | 25-AUG-20    |
> | 26-AUG-20    |
> | 27-AUG-20    |
> | 28-AUG-20    |
> | 31-AUG-20    |
> | 01-SEP-20    |
> | 02-SEP-20    |
> | 03-SEP-20    |
> | 04-SEP-20    |
> | 07-SEP-20    |
> | 08-SEP-20    |
> | 09-SEP-20    |
> | 10-SEP-20    |
> | 11-SEP-20    |
> | 14-SEP-20    |
> | 15-SEP-20    |
> | 16-SEP-20    |
> | 17-SEP-20    |
> | 18-SEP-20    |
> | 21-SEP-20    |
> | 22-SEP-20    |
> | 23-SEP-20    |
> | 24-SEP-20    |
> | 25-SEP-20    |
> | 28-SEP-20    |
> | 29-SEP-20    |
> | 30-SEP-20    |
> | 01-OCT-20    |
> | 02-OCT-20    |
> | 05-OCT-20    |
> | 06-OCT-20    |
> | 07-OCT-20    |
> | 08-OCT-20    |
> | 09-OCT-20    |
> | 12-OCT-20    |
> | 13-OCT-20    |
> | 14-OCT-20    |
> | 15-OCT-20    |
> | 16-OCT-20    |
> | 19-OCT-20    |
> | 20-OCT-20    |
> | 21-OCT-20    |
> | 22-OCT-20    |
> | 23-OCT-20    |
> | 26-OCT-20    |
> | 27-OCT-20    |
> | 28-OCT-20    |
> | 29-OCT-20    |
> | 30-OCT-20    |
> | 02-NOV-20    |
> | 03-NOV-20    |
> | 04-NOV-20    |
> | 05-NOV-20    |
> | 06-NOV-20    |
> | 09-NOV-20    |
> | 10-NOV-20    |
> | 11-NOV-20    |
> | 12-NOV-20    |
> | 13-NOV-20    |
> | 16-NOV-20    |
> | 17-NOV-20    |
> | 18-NOV-20    |
> | 19-NOV-20    |
> | 20-NOV-20    |
> | 23-NOV-20    |
> | 24-NOV-20    |
> | 25-NOV-20    |
> | 26-NOV-20    |
> | 27-NOV-20    |
> | 30-NOV-20    |
> | 01-DEC-20    |
> | 02-DEC-20    |
> | 03-DEC-20    |
> | 04-DEC-20    |
> | 07-DEC-20    |
> | 08-DEC-20    |
> | 09-DEC-20    |
> | 10-DEC-20    |
> | 11-DEC-20    |
> | 14-DEC-20    |
> | 15-DEC-20    |
> | 16-DEC-20    |
> | 17-DEC-20    |
> | 18-DEC-20    |
> | 21-DEC-20    |
> | 22-DEC-20    |
> | 23-DEC-20    |
> | 24-DEC-20    |
> | 25-DEC-20    |
> | 28-DEC-20    |
> | 29-DEC-20    |
> | 30-DEC-20    |
> | 31-DEC-20    |
> | 01-JAN-21    |
> | 04-JAN-21    |
> | 05-JAN-21    |
> | 06-JAN-21    |
> | 07-JAN-21    |
> | 08-JAN-21    |
> | 11-JAN-21    |
> | 12-JAN-21    |
> | 13-JAN-21    |
> | 14-JAN-21    |
> | 15-JAN-21    |
> | 18-JAN-21    |
> | 19-JAN-21    |
> | 20-JAN-21    |
> | 21-JAN-21    |
> | 22-JAN-21    |
> | 25-JAN-21    |
> | 26-JAN-21    |
> | 27-JAN-21    |
> | 28-JAN-21    |
> | 29-JAN-21    |
> | 01-FEB-21    |
> | 02-FEB-21    |
> | 03-FEB-21    |
> | 04-FEB-21    |
> | 05-FEB-21    |
> | 08-FEB-21    |
> | 09-FEB-21    |
> | 10-FEB-21    |
> | 11-FEB-21    |
> | 12-FEB-21    |
> | 15-FEB-21    |
> | 16-FEB-21    |
> | 17-FEB-21    |
> | 18-FEB-21    |
> | 19-FEB-21    |
> | 22-FEB-21    |
> | 23-FEB-21    |
> | 24-FEB-21    |
> | 25-FEB-21    |
> | 26-FEB-21    |
> | 01-MAR-21    |
> | 02-MAR-21    |
> | 03-MAR-21    |
> | 04-MAR-21    |
> | 05-MAR-21    |
> | 08-MAR-21    |
> | 09-MAR-21    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d97a72ff3bd2702c50a2feae7f02ec9a)*